# A very simple limit question

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Does anyone know I can solve for the limit of (1/n!)^(1/n) ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking about this limit $\lim_{n  \to \infty }(1/n!)^{1/n}$?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the limit I am talking about